# My laptop disconnects from one particular Wi-Fi network

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, laptop

I have a Lenovo laptop running Windows 10, and recently I've been losing internet connection from my Wi-Fi and unable to reconnect. I am able to connect to the network, but there's no connectivity to the internet. I have no problems when I connect to other networks, and all of the other devices in the house have no problem connecting to that network - it's just the connection between my laptop and that network.

I've noticed this tends to happen after I open my laptop for the first time, so it's been in sleep mode. Usually I can run the troubleshooter and have it fix the issue, but then lose it again. I can fix it once or twice, but eventually the troubleshooter is unable to fix the problem, with the message

> "Wi-Fi" doesn't have a valid IP configuration

I've tried a number of solutions I've found online, including uninstalling the driver, releasing/renewing the IP address, and resetting the TCP/IP. The only way I've found to fix it at this point is to power cycle the router and modem, which is strange to me because my computer is the only one having the problem.

Any ideas what's causing this problem and how to find a more permanent fix? Or at least a fix that doesn't involve resetting the router and causing an outage for everyone else in the house?

**Updates to address comments:**
I've been using this router and modem combo for over 6 months and haven't had any issues until a couple days ago. The other networks I've tried connecting to have been mobile hot spots, so not a long term solution.

My network adapter is a Qualcomm Atheros QCA61x4A Wireless Network Adapter, our router is a Netgear R6300, and the modem is a Netgear CM1000.

I tried updating both the wireless driver and router firmware, but both are up to date.

Comment: Please advise the make and model of the WiFi adapter in the laptop, or if you don't know, advise the model part number of your Lenovo from its serial number sticker. Also, what is the make and model of the WiFi router which provides the WiFi network? Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit] And, John's suggestions below are worthwhile.

Comment: @K7AAY Added the requested details.

Answer (score 2):

*I have no problems when I connect to other networks .....*

It may be a compatibility issue between this computer and this router. The above post seems clear:  Connect to any network except this one.

Two things to do:

1. Update the wireless driver on the computer to a newer version.
2. Update the firmware on the router you are connecting to.

Note: Upon reading your edits, I suggest a USB Wireless card. I have found Intel Wireless works very well with Windows 10 against a variety of routers.

Comment: I updated my question to address your suggestions. Unfortunately everything is up to date.